# ubuntu 20.04: suddenly 'p' key and up / down key not work

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

All keyboard keys and also 'p' key and up/down key workd in Ubuntu 20.04. but suddenly 'p' key and up/down key  dose not work and i don't why and how to fix it? (laptop model: asus n43)

Thank you very much for your help.